# Mysql: which datatype must be used to store mongo db document's object id

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sqldatatypes, objectid

The use case is, I have some of our product data present in Mongodb, while some data is present in MySQL.

So, the data that will reside in MySQL is:

```
product_skus (MySQL table) having columns - 
product_sku_id,
product_id (this will be the ObjectId of the product document stored in Mongodb)

product (Mongo Collection)
_id (ObjectId - referenced in product_skus table as product_id)
and some other product attributes...
```

To create a connection between the two, I need to store document's object id in MYSQL. Which datatype should I use for storing objectId in MYSQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am creating a new table in MySQL and beforehand need to know which datatype must be suitable for storing Mongo's Object id so as to link the data in MySQL table and Mongo document. Editing the question for being much clear.

Comment: You can probably store it as a varchar of [`24 length`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Comment: @NicoHaase Elaborated my question for making it clearer.

Comment: Please add the most important detail: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you looked at using the new MySQL Shell (mysqlsh)'s bson import function feature - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-json-bson.html

Comment: @DaveStokes I tried what Kunal has suggested, i.e. storing it as varchar of length 24. It is working fine. Isn't it the right way to store?